# R error after upgrading PostgreSQL from v9 to 9.2

Tags: r, postgresql

After upgrade I have started getting this error. The interesting aspect is that I don't get any errors when I run the code in R Terminal. Running a batch command  as "R CMD test.R" get the error.

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("L0", "Date", "Close", "Change",  : 

  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

R code goes like this :

```
   require(RPostgreSQL);

   drv_generic <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

   dbcon <- dbConnect( drv=drv_generic, "192.168.15.120", port=8085, user="test",password="yyyyyy", dbname="testdb" )

   qs <- sprintf("select * from some_function_name('%s', '%s', %d,
                        'id, tdate, cl, chg, factor')
                        as (L0 integer, \"Date\" date, \"Close\" double precision,    \"Change\" double precision,
                        \"Factor\" double precision)",
                    as.character(fromdate,format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                    as.character(todate,format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                    id );

   r = dbGetQuery( dbcon, qs,stringsAsFactors=F );

   colnames(r) <- c("L0","Date","Close","Change", "Adj");
```

Comment: Thanks Craig for the edits. Will be careful next time.